# Inno Setup unable to find image files

Tags: ant, javafx-2, inno-setup, netbeans-7

I am trying to package a JavaFX application using NetBeans & Inno setup. I have placed the custom .iss file and the images under Sample/package/windows folder. Ant CLASSPATH is also updated.

When I an trying to build the project, the compiler picks up the custom .iss file, but throws a file not found error.

```
Reading file (WizardImageFile)    
File: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\build3064710805837836647.fxbundler\imageswin-app.image\Sample.bmp
Error on line 34 in C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\build3064710805837836647.fxbundler\images\win-app.image\Sample.iss: Could not read "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\build3064710805837836647.fxbundler\images\win-app.image\Sample.bmp".

Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
Compile aborted.
```

Sample.bmp file is present under Sample/package/windows

Comment: I don't know NetBeans, but doesn't every build delete a temp folder of a previous build and create a new one ? Isn't there an option to deploy the files to a non-temporary folder (some sort of release build configuration) ? Building a setup from files from a temp folder is not reliable! How would you even version your project ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem here. The custom iss file should have the absolute path of the image file.

Comment: Well, then why did you show in your question absolute paths ? But still, deploying from temporary folder is a bad idea.

Comment: As I have already mentioned in my question that the custom files are placed at Sample/package/windows folder which is not a temp folder. 

NetBeans copies the custom files to a temp build directory over which I have no control.

And the output I have given in the question is from NetBeans.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you have checked that the file on the absolute path reported by the compiler error message exists.